# An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" in directory

Tags: java, maven, npm, npm-install, maven-antrun-plugin

Am trying to run the below maven command in mnet module, but am facing the below-mentioned error.

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (execute-script-prod) on project mnetWebApp: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "D:\Bishop\PROJECT\server\mnet\mnetWebApp\src\main\ngapp"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="D:\Bishop\PROJECT\server\mnet\mnetWebApp/src/main/ngapp" executable="npm">... @ 4:105 in D:\Bishop\PROJECT\server\mnet\mnetWebApp\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

I have kept the path in Environmental variables, and spent quite long time on googling, still i couldn't find the root cause.

I can able to check the npm --version and all.

Below images are the env variables config

System variable for use path

[image]

Systems Variable for user

[image]

System Variables image

[image]

Edit:

If I execute `ng version` am getting this output, where you can see some issues with package manager

[image]

if I execute `npm version` am getting below output

[image]

Comment: Can you run npm from the command line? Which directory is the executable in?

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227810/run-npm-ng-commands-using-ant-script-on-windows-the-system-cannot-find-the-fi

Comment: as per they mentioned in that ticket in pom level already npm.cmd is mentioned. still am facing this error.

Comment: ```npm@6.14.15 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm``` this is were it is present